# vagrant laravel vhost set up

Tags: laravel, vagrant, puppet

So i have a public network VM set up with Vagrant and PuPHPet to get an apache web server up and running. I'm using Laravel as my framework of choice. I can access my site in my browser by visiting the following:

`http://192.168.1.14/public/index.php/`

Using PuPHPet i configured my `vhost` to use "phptest.dev" as the Server Name.

I'm a little stuck on how i should set a `vhost` to prettify my url. I'm not sure where the "phptest.dev" server name comes into play. I can't ping phptest.dev and get anything back.

What is the proper way to set this up? I'd like to visit "phptest.dev" in my browser to see my site. I think i need to add an `.htaccess` file to route all requests through the 'public/index.php` file so i can get that out of the url but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know PuPHPet but I can answer in a generic way.

You can use `/etc/hosts` file to do name resolution, as long as you haven't changed `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

For example in `/etc/hosts`, add

```
192.168.1.14    phptest.dev
```

You should be able to ping the hostname from within the VM.

Suppose you are using Debian/Ubuntu, the sites configuration file is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/phptest.dev.conf`

> NOTE: don't forget to create a symbolic link in `sites-enabled`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin EMAIL
    DocumentRoot /path/to/php
    ServerName  phptest.dev
    ServerAlias www.phptest.dev

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /path/to/php>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phptest.dev-error_log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phptest.dev-access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Do a `service apache2 reload` or `restart` and see if you can access by using phptest.dev

Answer (score 1):

I can't respond directly to Terry Wang, but he's mostly right.

Ignore everything past his 4th line, though, because PuPHPet takes care of setting up the vhost in your VM for you.

You simply need to tell your local machine (your Mac or your Windows or maybe your Linux machine) that the domain `phptest.dev` is located at ip address `192.168.1.14`.

That's why you need to edit your hosts file.